# Pythonic way to check if string date is older than 5 days

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have 2 dates in string format

```
days = 5
date1 ="24 May 2021"
```

I want to check if another date is within the range of 5 days of date 1.

```
date2 = "11 May 2021"
date3 = "20 May 2021"
```

Here, date3 will be printed and date 2 will not be printed.

What is the best pythonic way to do this?

Comment: use `datetime`?

Comment: Use `datetime.strptime` to turn the strings into `datetime` objects, then `if reference_date + timedelta(days=5) > date2: ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

days = 5
date = "24 May 2021"
if datetime.strptime(date, "%d %b %Y") + timedelta(days=days) > datetime.today():
    print(f"It's less than {days} days ago")
else:
    print(f"It's more than {days} days ago")
```